# Laravel cron job does not execute commands

Tags: php, laravel, cron, jobs, host

My Cron Job was working **fine**, but **today** I detected that the commands were not executed. I wrote a Log info in the schedule function in kernel file but it doesn't run and doesn't print any errors/messages to the logs file.

**Log and one of the commands in kernel**

[commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpYCt.png)

**And this is my Cron Job that is execute every minute.**

Cron Job

[image]

My log file still **empty** I print a log info from controller and the message was printed correct.

**UPDATE**

When I press the View Output Button in Hostinger does not show errors.

[View Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOq6c.png)

Now i just created a **script.sh** with the following

[script.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBKE6.png)

After press the View output button return this message

[view output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wLkY.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, let me suggest you a youtube video i made on how to set up cron jobs on the server (it is in spanish) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwn-uBHCjFM

Comment: Your CRON job is set to run every minute. Most hosting companies will block that because it is a severe drain on server resources.

Comment: just run `php artisan schedule:run` and see if there is an error. Otherwise, your cron process might have hanged or something, restarting the cron service should work in such a case.

Comment: I run it and it works perfectly locally, was working fine, but from yesterday stop working and don't return any errors i checked the file structure and nothing was changed.